# MySQL Full-Text Search index on InnoDB table and missing results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

A customer notifies me that the search of an application we have developed for him is not working properly. The search is based on queries on Full-Text Search indexes on InnoDB tables in MySQL 5.6 (the first version that supported it).

When performing the query manually I check that it only returns 1 result when it should return 2. I tried with other search terms and the same table row is always omitted. The same queries using LIKE works well.

When trying to replicate the problem in a virtualized environment with the same OS and MySQL server versions I am unable to reproduce it, as the query works correctly after restoring a database dump.

After trying several options what has worked is to run OPTIMIZE TABLE. The search query works well after optimizing the table, showing the missing record.

Why does this happen? What is the explanation for this problem and how can it be detected or prevented?

Comment: Please show us the SELECT and the missing row.

Comment: The query is something like this: `SELECT * FROM workers WHERE MATCH (name, surname) AGAINST('+rosario' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`. The missing row has nothing special, but was updated recently (has timestamp columns for create/update) and the others dont. This is why a locked row seems possible...

Comment: File a bug report - bugs.mysql.com

Comment: To file a bug I must be able to reproduce the problem, and I can't. This is why I'm posting it here, to know if anyone else had this problem and knows how to reproduce/resolve it...

Answer (score 0):

i dont know much about your code, your database, your queries, but i see only 2 situations :

- a row level locking which is never released : (may be a bug in mysql) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html
- table corruption : i'm not sure if OPTIMIZE TABLE is repairing anything or only reducing fragmentation.

Comment: Thank you Raphael. The first option makes more sense, as I assume that a corrupted table would prevent any records from being read (it has already happened to me). If it happens again I will try to see if there are locked records, but at the moment I don't know how to reproduce the problem....